# Function scopes with tensorflow sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm restoring a Tensorflow graph from a checkpoint file, and then attempting to run several different feedforward computations with the loaded model.

To keep the code modular, though, I'd like to put the feedforward computations in separate functions. What's the right way to pass around the Tensorflow session? Right now, I have it structured as follows:

```py
def setup_graph(ckpt_file):
    sess = tf.Session():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt_file)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    # [ Here, get some placeholder tensors in the graph and save into placeholders dict ]
    return sess, graph, placeholders

# Function 1 using the restored model
def predict(sess, graph, placeholders, input_sound):
    # Use the graph being passed around to get other tensors we need
    pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("pred:0")
    # Use the session being passed around to evaluate the tensors we need
    prediction = sess.run([pred], feed_dict={placeholders["input"]: input_sound})

 # Function 2 using the restored model
 def get_embedding(sess, graph, placeholders, input_sound):
     embed = graph.get_tensor_by_name("embed:0")
     embedding = sess.run([embed], feed_dict={placeholders["input"]: input_sound})
```

It feels slightly wrong to pass around an open tensorflow session between functions, but I'm not sure how else to maintain modularity. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a clean way to do this?